# Comparing dates in angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, date

In my Angular program, I'm trying to filter an array based on if each of the dates are between 2 set dates. I have the dates set to be the first and the last of the current month:

`StartDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1);
 EndDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1, 0);`

I have the user choose which days they would like to see the results of the array for:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px;">
     <label class="col-sm-5" style="text-align: right;">Start Date</label>
     <div class="col-sm-7">
         <input class="form-control" type="date" id="StartDate" [ngModel]="StartDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="StartDate=$event" name="StartDate" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; text-align: center;">
      <label class="col-sm-5" style="text-align: right;">End Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="EndDate" [ngModel]="EndDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="EndDate=$event" name="EndDate" />
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and then, I call a function that filters the array based on those dates:

```js
setValues(): void {
    this.datePTO = this.ptoData.filter(pto => pto.date > this.StartDate && pto.date < this.EndDate);
}
```

If the user keeps the dates the same and then tries to see the array, it won't have anything in it. Whereas, if they change the dates at all, the array will fill with what should be in it. I've found out that whenever the user changes the dates, they change to string and then are compared somehow. How can I fix this so that they can just hit the button if the date range they want is the default one shown?

Comment: your `pto.date`, is that a string or a date?

Comment: @mTv it's a date and whenever the user enters a date in the input box for the variables `startDate` and `endDate`, they become strings, are compared with `pto.date` and the correct array is printed. It just doesn't work for the default values for some reason. I tried converting them to strings and then comparing but I get an error where it says I can't compare a date (`pto.date`) to a string (`startDate` or `endDate`)

Comment: Hm. Are you sure `pto.date` is a `Date`? Have you tried printing `typeof pto.date`? Seems really wierd that it works when the user sets the date(as a String), but not when you convert them initially.

Its also weird that the between comparison works with string and date types. Date is converted to number before comparison(`.valueOf()`), and a string compared to a number(<, >, ==, ===) always returns `false`.

Comment: @mTv damn, nevermind. Okay so in my model, it's declared as a date, but i just looped through and did a `console.log` and they all printed out as strings. But, if I change my filter to be `this.datePTO = this.ptoData.filter(pto => pto.date > this.StartDate.toDateString()` or `.toString`, it says "`Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'string'.`"

Comment: Good at least it makes some sense then:P.
try doing `.toISOString()` when you first declare `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Wait, why does give that error with the `.toString()` on? does that mean the compiler think `pto.date` is a `Date` but it actually isn't? Or maybe I'm just confusing myself atm.

Comment: @mTv whenever I do that, I still get an error in `this.datePTO = this.ptoData.filter(pto => pto.date > this.StartDate && pto.date < this.EndDate);` that says "`Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'string'.`" which is really weird because whenever I looped through and printed out the ptoData[i].date, it printed out as a string but in my filter function, it's treated like a date (which is what it should be and is declared as)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149738/discussion-between-mtv-and-asdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a type issue.

When you compare `Date` types, they are converted to `number` through the function `valueOf()`. Comparing a `String` to a `number` seems to always return `false`. This is probably why it doesn't work until you set the dates again so that the `StartDate` and `EndDate` becomes `String` types.

I suggest either just sticking to strings as long as its in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. By that i mean, declare `StartDate` and `EndDate` as strings initally instead of dates.

Or you can parse the dates in your input and/or in the `setValues` function using something like this:

```
parseDate(dateString: string): Date {
    if (dateString) {
        return new Date(dateString);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```